# How to add decimal column to existing table in Laravel 5.3 migration

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have tried following 3 codes in a Laravel 5.3 project to add new decimal column to an existing table. But it's giving same error every time.

```
Schema::table('mileages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->addColumn('decimal', 'cost');
});
```

and

```
Schema::table('mileages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->addColumn('decimal', 'cost', ['default'=>0]);
});
```

and

```
Schema::table('mileages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->addColumn('decimal', 'cost', ['default'=>'0,0']);
});
```

The error was :

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' ) not null' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `mileages` add `cost` decimal (, ) not null)
```

am i missing something ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're trying to use `->addColumn()` which isn't quite the right syntax.

Create a new migration, `php artisan make:migrate add_cost_column_to_mileages`.

Then inside your migration, you want it to look like this for up:

```
Schema::table('mileages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->decimal('cost', 5,2); //Substitute 5,2 for your desired precision
});
```

And this for down:

```
Schema::table('mileages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('cost');
});
```

This is from the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns), although they don't make it explicitly clear.

Comment: Yes it's working. Thank you!. Also `$table->addColumn('decimal', 'cost', ['default' => 0, 'total' => 8, 'places' => 2]);` is working.

Answer (score 1):

```html
Schema::table('mileages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->addColumn('decimal',2);
});
```